# sql database: table with 2 column (id name) and 2 primary key Third Normal Form Boyce-Codd Normal Form

Tags: sql, primary-key, bcnf, third-normal-form

Imagine the following table. In my case, I am completely sure that `name` needs to be `unique` and `not null` [unique+not null = primary key]. Therefore `name` is a primary key. For some reasons (probably by habit), I have naturally created a primary key `id` column of type int.

Other assumptions: I absolutely need to keep `name` in my table and I am absolutely sure that `name` (of type `varchar`)  will never exceed 20 characters.

Now my first question is [probably close question with yes or no expected]: do I respect BCNF Boyce-Codd Normal Form if I create such a table?

Second optional question [probably open question]: is it good practice to create column `id` in this case?

```
  CREATE TABLE Y (
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, name)
    );
```

Comment: `name` and `id` both are *candidate keys*. Only one of them can be chosen as a primary key. And to violate BCNF you''ll need at least three columns(given it has a PK).

Comment: *unique + not null = candidate key*

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Yes you are right. It is my mistake. I should have said unique + not null = candidate key

Comment: @joop Yes you are right. It is my mistake. I should have said unique + not null = candidate key. OK so I have to chose only one primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each column is unique, you probably want either

```
CREATE TABLE Y (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(20) not null unique,
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE Y (
  id int not null unique,
  name varchar(20) not null unique
);
```

The FDs here are id->name and name->id.

Informally, you satisfy BCNF when every arrow in your FDs is an arrow out of a candidate key. So this satisfies BCNF.

It's not a good thing to create a surrogate id column *out of habit*. Think first, and make yourself aware of the tradeoffs and side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Although relations comprising only two attributes are always in BCNF, your question is a bit difficult to answer as the text does not correspond with the table design.

If I take your table design as base for answering the first question: You create a table `Y` comprising two attributes `id` and `name`, which are the only attributes of `Y`and which together form the only key, then it is always in BCNF.

When I take your textual description, where you state that `name` is unique (in terms of the relational model a key), then one has to think of the meaning of the surrogate attribute (or key?) `id`:

a. If `id` is a key, too, then FDs are `id->name; name->id`, where `id`
    is a key and `name` is a key, such that every FD has a key on his
    left hand side. BCNF is therefore fulfilled.

b. If `id`is not key on its own, but `name->id` holds, then it is still
    in BCNF (because the only FD has a key on his LHS). Though I would
    then not understand why you have an additional attribute `id` at
    all.

The main thing is, however, that your database scheme does simply not adhere to the rules stated in the text: The sole key with `(id, name)` is simply wrong expressed, because you should have `id` as primary key and `name` as unique constraint (i.e. an alternative key) or vice versa. Then it would be clearly in BCNF, and would correspond to option (a) mentioned above.

So it is not a question of BCNF or not, but a question of "scheme correct expressed or not".